# What is the shortest way in ruby to write these four instructions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
u = User.email_equals("tabaluga@gmail.com").first
s = u.setting
s.regular_info = false
s.save
```

Does anyone know how to write it shorter? Perhaps in one line? That would be awesome.

Comment: If you're using Rails then you should tag your question as such, otherwise there's no way of knowing how your code can be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
User.email_equals("tabaluga@gmail.com").first.setting.update_attribute(:regular_info, false)
```

(don't have a console handy to check, but think that should work ..)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how do you define your email_equals method, but Rails provides **Dynamic attribute-based finders** which returns the first match or nil for not found.

```
User.find_by_email("tabaluga@gmail.com").setting.update_attribute(:regular_info, false)
```

Comment: This is the best answer (IMHO).

Comment: Use `try` to handle the `nil` results returned by `find_by_email` and `settings` methods, i.e. `find_by_email("tabaluga@gmail.com").try(:setting).try(:update_attribute, :regular_info, false)`

Comment: @KandadaBoggu, if I want to handle nil in this case, then I prefer not using try. I prefer using find_by_email!, so I could rescue the exception or I split it into two lines with condition instead.

Comment: The `find_by_email` call doesn't throw exception. It will simply return `nil` upon not finding a match. Only `find` method throws `RecordNotFound` exception.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu, `find_by_email` doesn't raise the exception when it can't found, but `find_by_email!` does raise the exception.

Comment: @Samnang `find_by_email` and `find_by_email!` are separate methods. So it is expected that they behave differently. Any method that ends with a `!` in ruby is supposed to modify the data or throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can write this in one line, I would recommend against it. This makes your code less readable and maintainable.

This is also an isolated example; realistically the email would not be hardcoded, it would be stored in its own variable and might be an argument.

### One Liner

```rb
User.email_equals("tabaluga@gmail.com").first.setting.update_attribute(:regular_info, false)
```

### Two Liner

```rb
user = User.email_equals("tabaluga@gmail.com").first
user.setting.update_attribute(:regular_info, false)

# Or...
user_setting = User.email_equals("tabaluga@gmail.com").first.setting
user_setting.update_attribute(:regular_info, false)

# More readable, but not maintainable
User.email_equals("tabaluga@gmail.com").first \ 
  .setting.update_attribute(:regular_info, false)
```

### Three Liner

```rb
user = User.email_equals("tabaluga@gmail.com").first
setting = user.setting
setting.update_attribute(:regular_info, false)
```